How to delete AWS SNS topics and SQS queues in bulk with AWS CLI by a pattern?
I have many topics and queues named in the same pattern. Now I need to delete them all in bulk using some pattern with a wildcard. The AWS CLI only allows deleting one by one. Same in the AWS Console - the list of queues and topics have radio boxes in their rows allowing to delete one by one only. How to delete multiple items at once by a pattern? What script can I use for that?

Are you skilled in a scripting language, such as shell or Python?

@JohnRotenstein I know that RTFM is the best answer. But I've asked a specific question because I've faced a specific issue with no easy answers in google. The proposed solution below requires some specific knowledge of AWS CLI that I may lack at the moment.

The solution below uses shell scripting to call the AWS CLI for one Amazon SNS Topic at a time. Similarly, it would be possible to write a loop in Python that calls the Amazon SNS API once for each topic. These are ways to perform a 'bulk' deletion. I was asking for your preferred programming language so that we could assist you in writing such a script.

Bash is preferable because we need the script to be executed in environments without Python. BTW, the Python variant may also help someone else. Thank you.

Using the CLI in your shell or CloudShell you can do something like:
topics=$(aws sns list-topics --query 'Topics[*]' --output text | grep <YOUR_PATTERN>)
for topic in $topics 
do 
  echo "Deleting topic" $topic
  aws sns delete-topic --topic-arn $topic
done

Do the same with the CLI commands for sqs.

you can create script for your task and you can use cli in script for bulk deletion
To Delete SNS Topics by Pattern:
#!/bin/bash
aws sns list-topics --query 'Topics[].TopicArn' --output text | grep "<your-pattern>" | while read -r topic_arn
do
    echo "Deleting SNS topic: $topic_arn"
    aws sns delete-topic --topic-arn "$topic_arn"
done

To Delete SQS Queues by Pattern:
#!/bin/bash
aws sqs list-queues --query 'QueueUrls[]' --output text | grep "your-pattern" | while read -r queue_url
do
    echo "Deleting SQS queue: $queue_url"
    aws sqs delete-queue --queue-url "$queue_url"
done


Thank you for your suggestion. But it seems it requires changes. Because the loop doesn't work, the echo command is executed only once and prints all found topics/queues at once.
